# Modifications in evaluate.py for other architectures in tensorflow poets

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

There's a script for measuring the model's performance at [tensorflow-for-poets-2/scripts/evaluate.py](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2/blob/master/scripts/evaluate.py).  That script was originally written for mobilenet models but can be modified for other architectures accordingly. What should I write in line [41](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2/blob/master/scripts/evaluate.py#L41)

```
logits = graph.get_tensor_by_name("final_training_ops/Wx_plus_b/add:0").
```

I'm getting `KeyError:

> The name final_training_ops/Wx_plus_b/add:0' refers to a Tensor which
>   does not exist. The operation, 'final_training_ops/Wx_plus_b/add',
>   does not exist in the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out myself. Given a .pb file, we can view the operations in frozen .pb TensorFlow graphs using this [code](https://gist.github.com/sunsided/88d24bf44068fe0fe5b88f09a1bee92a). So, we need to replace the line [41](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2/blob/master/scripts/evaluate.py#L41) with the last operation according to our .pb file.